# ASP.NET with MVC same-ish route does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Starting to learn ASP.NET with React and I'm actually struggling with properly setting my routes.

In the Startup.cs file I use the generated route pattern that I modify slightly :

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action}");
});
```

In my controller I declare 2 different routes that I think respect the pattern :

```
{
  [ApiController]
  [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
  public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
  {
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", 
"Scorching"
    };

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
      var rng = new Random();
      return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
      {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index * 2),
        TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
      })
      .ToArray();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Test()
    {
      var rng = new Random();
      return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
      {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index * 2),
        TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
      })
      .ToArray();
    }
  }
}
```

In my React app, if I do this :

```
const response = await fetch('https://localhost:5001/weatherforecast/Get');
const data = await response.json();
```

it works perfectly fine I get the datas I need. But then if I do this :

```
const response = await fetch('https://localhost:5001/weatherforecast/Test');
const data = await response.json();
```

I get nothing.

So basically, what exactly is wrong with this? How is the 'Test' route not returning anything considering it's the exact same parttern [same controller]/[different action]?

Comment: Hi @UmbrellaCorpAgent, Please try to send request by browser or postman to the asp.net core project and check if `weatherforecast/Test` could be hit. Also could you please share the error message when you fetch api in react project?

Comment: Same thing with the broswer or postman, the first one works, the second one does not

Comment: Hi @UmbrellaCorpAgent, I think maybe your project did something wrong, it works well in my project. Please  share your Startup.cs. Actually did you try the following answer, specific the route should work.

Comment: I just got someone to help me figuring out the problem. It was a code 12. I ran the app using 'dotnet run'. So basically I had the old version running all the time without the changes taken into consideration. Using 'dotnet watch' got it to work fine... Embarassing to say the least...

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem will be solved if declare the route of every method above of it forexample like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/WeatherForecast/Get"]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
  ....
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("/WeatherForecast/Test"]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Test()
{
  ....
}
```